# How do I use a regular expression to match a number as an integer?

Tags: ruby, regex

When I match a number using a regular expression I get it as a string:

```
?> 'TestingSubject2981'.match /\d+$/
=> #<MatchData "2981">
```

Is it somehow possible to get the number as an integer without some `to_i`s?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `to_i`?

Comment: This might be a comparison with Perl. Perl would extract a scalar variable of course, and if it happened to look like number, then Perl would be happy to treat it as such. But then Perl doesn't have native classes for all data types, so is free to do that for costs elsewhere.

Comment: @sawa: Programmers are lazy. That's why.

Comment: @nhahtdh My impression is that beginners are more lazy than they should be. Experienced programmers know where to be lazy.

Comment: +1 @NeilSlater. And that behavior leads to other problems in Perl that opened some real rabbit-holes occasionally.

Comment: You could monkey patch `String` with a method like `.extract_integers` that does your regex test and then uses `to_i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that regular expressions only work on strings, not on other data types.

A regex has patterns to match numbers, but those still only find the characters that represent the number, not the binary values that we'd use for math. Once the engine returns the matches, they're still characters, so we have to use `to_i` to convert them to their binary representations.

MMM-kay?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not supposed to convert strings to integers (or any other class for that matter). The only way I can see is using the [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) method. And I can't see why you would avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use to get number from string:

```
'TestingSubject2981'.scan(/\d+/)[0].to_i
```